# Reduction of rows in a table

Tags: mysql, row

How would I make this so that it just contains one row without any null values. I am unsure how to go about doing this.

`+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| id |    Col1     |     Col2     |         Col3          |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | description | null         | null                  |
|  1 | null        | descriptions | null                  |
|  1 | null        | null         | different description |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+`

Example of what I want to have

`+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| id |    Col1     |     Col2     |         Col3          |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | description | descriptions | different description |
+----+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+`

Comment: you want  remove 2 rows  and let only one row with all column with a not null value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with two query
first an insert/select with (fake) aggregation function and group by for populate all the column of a row

```
  insert into my_table (id, col1, col2,col3)
  select id, max(col1), max(col2), max(col3)
  from my_table 
  group by id
  ;
```

second  a delete for remove the row with some null coll

```
  delete from 
  my_table 
  where col1 is null
  or col2 is null
  or col3 is null
  ;
```